# Pycaret 3.0, predict_model not showing anything

Tags: python, pycaret

Pycaret 3.0 "predict_model" is not working.

python = 3.11
pycaret = 3.0

loadmodel is worked but loadmodel is not.

Tried with printing the loaded model and it worked.
But when I tried printing prediction, nothing appeared.

There is no any error message, but the code below "predict_model" line not working.

Comment: This question needs both **content** and **quality**. You have not posed any specific question, the scope of this post is way too broad, and you didn't provide any details of what you have tried to resolve this issue on your own. Additionally, you need to provide enough code so that the community can answer your question. StackOverflow requires that you provide a minimum reproducible example. Right now, you are saying **something doesn't work, how I do I fix it?** but you haven't provided the community anything to work with. Read below 

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new to stackoverflow.
About last month, I used Pycaret as an AutoML tool to help me do model training.
I've installed pycaret 2.3.10 to use load_model and predict_model on VScode (After do training on colab). But now, new version pycaret is just released and I want to try. But I have a problem after installing it. Even the code is the same as the last month, predict_model is not working. But load_model still works well. Also sorry for my English, I'm a foreign student trying to learn English and Programming.

Answer (score 0):

pycaret does not support Python 3.11 yet (https://pypi.org/project/pycaret/)
Please use python 3.10 or below.